# Convert date which is a text data type to specific format in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

How can we convert 15jan2018 which is a text datatype to 15JAN2018.

I am able to convert if it is date datatype.

Comment: Are you actually converting anything? Seems like you just need `UPPER` case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_date`:

```
SELECT to_date('15jan2018', 'DDmonYYYY');

  to_date   
------------
 2018-01-15
(1 row)
```

Then use `to_char` to convert it to any format you want:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('15jan2018', 'DDmonYYYY'), 'DDMONYYYY');

  to_char  
-----------
 15JAN2018
(1 row)
```

Of course you can simply use `upper` in your specific case to convert it to upper case, but I guess that's not what you are looking for.

Finally, PostgreSQL's date input function is pretty flexible, so you can try to simply cast it:

```
SELECT '15jan2018'::date;

    date    
------------
 2018-01-15
(1 row)
```

This is useful if the format varies slightly.